# ubuntu 13.10 mongodb doesnt work after restart

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Hi I have installed mongodb as I did on last versions of ubuntu :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

but now when I restart I got:

mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Thu Jan  2 15:21:27.017 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed

when I try to do:

sudo service mongodb start
mongodb start/running, process 5371

I get same error msg when I want to connet to mongo..
What can I do ?

Comment: may be your connection is done through a proxy, if that's the case , you should export the proxy settings to your configuration first.

Comment: Can you confirm that the process is still running post start? (ps aux | grep mongod
)

Comment: ps aux | grep mongod 
baku      5971  0.0  0.0  14884   956 pts/12   S+   09:23   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod

Comment: If I do sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf it works fine.. but dont want to start on autostart.

Comment: Maybe you started 'mongod' the first time with 'sudo' and the DB and log files are all owned by 'root'?

Comment: yes You are right see: baku@baku-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/workspace/sgrouples$ mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf 
all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
can't open [/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log] for log file: errno:13 Permission denied
Bad logpath value: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"; terminating.
 :) thanks